# PHP 7 type declaration for symfony entities

Tags: php, symfony

With PHP 7 type declarations can be used to throw an exception if the provided parameter has another type than expected. Can this be used to only allow symfony entities?

```
/**
 * @param User|MyOtherEntity $entity
 */
public function serialize(TYPEHINTFORENTITY $entity)
{
    $json = json_decode($this->serializer->serialize(
        $entity,
        'json'
    ), true);

    return $json;
}

public function deserialize($json, string $class): TYPEHINTFORENTITY
{
    $entity = $this->serializer->deserialize(
        json_encode($json),
        'MyBundle\Entity\' . $class,
        'json',
        DeserializationContext::create()->setGroups(
            array('group')
        )
    );

    return $entity;
}
```

If I use the same function to serialize different entities I can't use

```
public function serialize(User $entity)
```

because that wouldn't allow entities of MyOtherEntity to be serialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entities are not "special" objects from PHP point of view.
You can approach this in two ways

1. Define a common interface (probably without any methods), typehint it and let all the entities implements this
2. Use the `object` type for typehint that was [introduced in PHP 7.2](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/object-typehint)

With first solution you are safe if someone tries to pass something that's not an implementation of this [interface](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php). Of course you need to remember that every time a new entity is created in the codebase, it should implement that interface.

With second solution you're not safe as in the point one but you still be sure that everything that's passed is not a scalar or primitive type

With first solution you'll end up writing something like

```
interface Entity { }
class FooEntity implements Entity { }
class BarEntity implements Entity { }
...
public function serialize(Entity $entity) { }
```

With second solution just

```
public function serialize(object $entity) { }
```

First solution is recommended if you need to allow *only* those kind of entities whereas second is more permissive: both of them are just fine to me but you need to focus on what are the rules for your code

### Edit

I've seen other answers suggesting to extend instead of implement an interface: please don't extend from a superclass if not strictly necessary as PHP classes can extend only from one class whereas them can implements multiple interfaces. Interface is the way to go if you need the first solution otherwise you'll be in trouble if you'll need some *real* extension imposed by the model

Answer (score 4):

The best way to use type hinting on different types of object is to use a common [Interface](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) implemented by all entities which should be valid for your function.

For example in your case I would use

```
public function serialize(\Serializable $entity)
```